# NoReverseMatch with django-addanother Edit button

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, reverse

I am trying add edit button to ModelForm with [django-addanother](https://django-addanother.readthedocs.io/en/latest/edit-related.html).
When I am adding only AddAnother everything works perfectly, but when I am trying add Edit button I am getting NoReverseMatch, the main difference is that I am using there **fk** and I do not know how to connect that with my primary_key

forms.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django_addanother.widgets import AddAnotherWidgetWrapper
from django_addanother.widgets import AddAnotherEditSelectedWidgetWrapper
class BookForm(PermissionRequiredMixin, ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'author', 'summary', 'tag', 'genre', 'language', 'book_format', 'read_date']
        #labels = 
        widgets = {
            'author': AddAnotherEditSelectedWidgetWrapper(
                forms.Select,
                reverse_lazy('author_form'),
                reverse_lazy('author_update', args=['__fk__']),
            ),
        }       
        permission_required = 'libraryapp.can_edit'
```

views.py

```
from django_addanother.views import CreatePopupMixin, UpdatePopupMixin

def book_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Book has been created!'))
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = BookForm()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = BookForm()
    return render(request, 'libraryapp/book_form.html', {'form': form})

class AuthorCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreatePopupMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = '__all__'
    permission_required = 'libraryapp.can_edit'

class AuthorUpdate(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdatePopupMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Author
    fields = '__all__'
    permission_required = 'libraryapp.can_edit'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('author/create/', views.AuthorCreate.as_view(), name='author_form'),
    path('author/<int:pk>/update/', views.AuthorUpdate.as_view(), name='author_update'),
    path('book/create/', views.book_create, name='book_form'),
```

So when I am using only AddAuthor it is working, but with Edit it alwyas get me this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /libraryapp/book/create/
Reverse for 'book_form' with arguments '('__fk__',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['libraryapp\\/book\\/create\\/$']

1   {% load i18n static %}
2   <div class="related-widget-wrapper">
3       {{ widget }}
4   
5       {% if edit_related_url %}
6       <a class="related-widget-wrapper-link change-related" id="change_id_{{ name }}"
7           href=""
8           data-href-template="{{ edit_related_url }}?{{ url_params }}"
9           title="{% blocktrans %}Edit related{% endblocktrans %}">
10          <img src="{% static edit_icon %}" alt="{% trans 'Edit' %}"/>
11      </a>
12      {% endif %}
13  
14      {% if add_related_url %}
15      <a class="related-widget-wrapper-link add-related" id="add_id_{{ name }}"
```

What should I change, I guess I should add another variable to render request in my book_create or something else?

Comment: Why are you passing `args=['__fk__']` ?

Comment: It is in BookForm in widgets: reverse_lazy('book_form', args=['__fk__']),

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I found a workaround for this in case anyone is still looking.

The 3 steps to solve it are:

1. Add a 'dummy' URL for the update view that contains '__fk__' in place of '<int:pk>'
2. Create a view for your dummy URL.
3. In the modelform, under widgets, remove the args from the url reverse for the edit button and change the url reference to point to the dummy.

For the code as written in this question:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('author/create/', views.AuthorCreate.as_view(), name='author_form'),
    path('author/<int:pk>/update/', views.AuthorUpdate.as_view(), name='author_update'),
    path('book/create/', views.book_create, name='book_form'),
    path('author/__fk__/update/', views.author_update_dummy, name='author_update_dummy'), #New path 
]
```

views.py

```
from django_addanother.views import CreatePopupMixin, UpdatePopupMixin
from django.http import HttpResponse #For the new view

def book_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Book has been created!'))
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            form = BookForm()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = BookForm()
    return render(request, 'libraryapp/book_form.html', {'form': form})

class AuthorCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreatePopupMixin, CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = '__all__'
    permission_required = 'libraryapp.can_edit'

class AuthorUpdate(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdatePopupMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Author
    fields = '__all__'
    permission_required = 'libraryapp.can_edit'

#The new view:
def author_update_dummy(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Page not found</h1>')
```

forms.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django_addanother.widgets import AddAnotherWidgetWrapper
from django_addanother.widgets import AddAnotherEditSelectedWidgetWrapper
class BookForm(PermissionRequiredMixin, ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'author', 'summary', 'tag', 'genre', 'language', 'book_format', 'read_date']
        #labels = 
        widgets = {
            'author': AddAnotherEditSelectedWidgetWrapper(
                forms.Select,
                reverse_lazy('author_form'),
                reverse_lazy('author_update_dummy'), #Removed the args and updated reference
            ),
        }       
        permission_required = 'libraryapp.can_edit'
```

The reason this is an issue comes down to rendering of the 'related_widget_wrapper.html' template included with django-addanother:

```
{% load i18n static %}
<div class="related-widget-wrapper">

    {{ widget }}
    {% if edit_related_url %}
    <br><a class="related-widget-wrapper-link change-related" id="change_id_{{ name }}"
        href=""
        data-href-template="{{ edit_related_url }}?{{ url_params }}"
        title="{% blocktrans %}Edit related{% endblocktrans %}">
        {% trans 'View/Update Info for Selected' %}
    </a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if add_related_url %}
    <br><a class="related-widget-wrapper-link add-related" id="add_id_{{ name }}"
        href="{{ add_related_url }}?{{ url_params }}"
        title="{% blocktrans %}Add another{% endblocktrans %}">
        {% trans 'Add New' %}
    </a>
    {% endif %}

</div>
```

When the page is first loaded (with the arguments as shown in django-addanother docs), {{ edit_related_url }} gets passed '__fk__' as an argument, but the update url is looking for an integer (the primary key) as an argument, and therefore {{ edit_related_url }} can't be properly resolved in the template.

Creating a dummy page and replacing '<int:id>' with '__fk__' allows you to take advantage of part of the coding in the admin RelatedObjectLookup.js file:

```
function updateRelatedObjectLinks(triggeringLink) {
        var $this = $(triggeringLink);
        var siblings = $this.nextAll('.view-related, .change-related, .delete-related');
        if (!siblings.length) {
            return;
        }
        var value = $this.val();
        if (value) {
            siblings.each(function() {
                var elm = $(this);
                elm.attr('href', elm.attr('data-href-template').replace('__fk__', value));
            });
        } else {
            siblings.removeAttr('href')
        }
    }
```

The dummy link doesn't load on the page because 'related_widget_wrapper.html' uses 'data-href-template' and no link is given for 'href.'

When you change the value in the dropdown, 'href' is populated by the data in 'data-href-template,' but first '__fk__' is replaced with the selected value from the dropdown. This value is the primary key for the correct row in the ForeignKey model (in this case, Author), so the updated URL links with the correct UpdateView.